# Need help grabbing data from SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I have a winform I am trying to save data to a SQL Server CE database and also retrieve that data.

I am unable to retrieve any data when I run the following in my winfom:

```
string lookupValue;

SqlCeConnection connection;
connection = new SqlCeConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source= LaZSolutions.sdf";

SqlCeCommand cmd2 = connection.CreateCommand();

if (txtOrderNum.Text != null)
{
   lookupValue = txtOrderNum.Text;
   cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, Customers.Address, Customers.City, Customers.State, Customers.Zip, Customers.Phone, Customers.Mobile, Customers.OrderNum, Customers.Comments, Customers.Email, Orders.OrderDate, Orders.OrderNum AS Expr1, Orders.Cost, Orders.Image FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.OrderNum = Orders.OrderNum WHERE (Orders.OrderNum = '" + lookupValue + "')";
}
else if (txtFName.Text != null && txtLName.Text != null)
{
   cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT Customers.*, Orders.* From Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Customers.OrderNum = Orders.OrderNum where Customers.Firstname = '" + Convert.ToString(txtFName.Text) + "' and Customers.LastName = '" + Convert.ToString(txtLName.Text) + "'";
}

connection.Open();
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlCeDataReader readData = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

if (readData != null)
{
   while (readData.Read())
      txtFName.Text = readData["FirstName"].ToString();
   txtLName.Text = readData["lastname"].ToString();
   txtAddress.Text = readData["address"].ToString();
   txtCity.Text = readData["city"].ToString();
   txtState.Text = readData["state"].ToString();
   txtZip.Text = readData["zip"].ToString();
   txtHPhone.Text = readData["phone"].ToString();
   txtMPhone.Text = readData["mobile"].ToString();
   txtComments.Text = readData["Comments"].ToString();
   txtEmail.Text = readData["email"].ToString();
   txtOrderNum.Text = readData["OrderNum"].ToString();
   txtOrderdate.Text = readData["orderdate"].ToString();
   lblPrice.Text = readData["Cost"].ToString();
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("No Results Found");
}
connection.Close();
```

Could some direct me to my error? The query returns 1 line when I run it in VS. Thank you.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with the line `while (readData.Read())`. Try putting { } around the code lines where you are setting the values and see if this helps.

```
    while (readData.Read())
    {
        txtFName.Text = readData["FirstName"].ToString();
        txtLName.Text = readData["lastname"].ToString();
        ...
        lblPrice.Text = readData["Cost"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You sure it does not lack the brace of the while loop

try this

```
 while (readData.Read())
{
                txtFName.Text = readData["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLName.Text = readData["lastname"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = readData["address"].ToString();
            txtCity.Text = readData["city"].ToString();
            txtState.Text = readData["state"].ToString();
            txtZip.Text = readData["zip"].ToString();
            txtHPhone.Text = readData["phone"].ToString();
            txtMPhone.Text = readData["mobile"].ToString();
            txtComments.Text = readData["Comments"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = readData["email"].ToString();
            txtOrderNum.Text = readData["OrderNum"].ToString();
            txtOrderdate.Text = readData["orderdate"].ToString();
            lblPrice.Text = readData["Cost"].ToString();
}
```

In C# if you omit the brace on a loop or a condition statement only the NEXT line is included by the block